# Loading Large Row Data into Cassandra using Java and CQLSSTableWriter

Tags: java, cassandra, bulk

I've been trying to load an enormously large data set into Cassandra using the SSTableLoader API for Java, but my program keeps timing out as I'm doing it.

I'm taking articles and breaking them down into word ngrams (unigrams, bigrams, trigrams). I have one keyspace with three columns families (unigrams, trigrams, bigrams). Within these column families, the row key would be the Document ID, then for every ngram within that document, a column would be added containing that ngram.

So an article with the ID of 'article1' and having the contents "This is a test sentence", the row would look like..

```
row id    |   col  | col | col |  col   |    col
----------------------------------------------------
article1  |  This  | is  |  a  |  test  |  sentence
```

This is the Java file I'm using to initiate the SSTableWriters and add data to them is:

```
package cassandrabulktest.cassandra;

import static NGramProperties.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.InvalidRequestException;
import org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter;



public class NGramLoader {
    private static final String UNIGRAM_SCHEMA = "CREATE TABLE articles.unigrams (" +
                                                      "docid text, " +
                                                      "unigram text, " +
                                                      "PRIMARY KEY (unigram, docid))";

    private static CQLSSTableWriter unigram_writer;

    private static final String BIGRAM_SCHEMA = "CREATE TABLE articles.bigrams (" +
                                                      "docid text, " +
                                                      "bigram text, " +
                                                      "PRIMARY KEY (bigram, docid))";

    private static CQLSSTableWriter bigram_writer;

    private static final String TRIGRAM_SCHEMA = "CREATE TABLE articles.trigrams (" +
                                                      "docid text, " +
                                                      "trigram text, " +
                                                      "PRIMARY KEY (trigram, docid))";

    private static CQLSSTableWriter trigram_writer;


    public static void initDirectories(String startdate, int count) {
        String[] grams = { "unigrams", "bigrams", "trigrams" };
        for (String gram : grams) {
            File f = new File(BASE_LOCATION + "/" + startdate + "/articles/" + gram + "/");
            f.mkdirs();
        }

        unigram_writer = CQLSSTableWriter.builder()
                .inDirectory(BASE_LOCATION + "/" + startdate + "/articles/unigrams/")
                .forTable(UNIGRAM_SCHEMA)
                .using("INSERT INTO articles.unigrams (docid, unigram) VALUES (?, ?)")
                .build();

         bigram_writer = CQLSSTableWriter.builder()
                .inDirectory(BASE_LOCATION + "/" + startdate + "/articles/bigrams/")
                .forTable(BIGRAM_SCHEMA)
                .using("INSERT INTO articles.bigrams (docid, bigram) VALUES (?, ?)")
                .build();

        trigram_writer = CQLSSTableWriter.builder()
                .inDirectory(BASE_LOCATION + "/" + startdate + "/articles/trigrams/")
                .forTable(TRIGRAM_SCHEMA)
                .using("INSERT INTO articles.trigrams (docid, trigram) VALUES (?, ?)")
                .build();
    }

    public static void load(String articleId, ArrayList<String> unigrams, ArrayList<String> bigrams, ArrayList<String> trigrams) throws IOException, InvalidRequestException {
        for (String unigram : unigrams) {
            unigram_writer.addRow(unigram, articleId);
        }

        for (String bigram : bigrams) {
            bigram_writer.addRow(bigram, articleId);
        }

        for (String trigram : trigrams) {
            trigram_writer.addRow(trigram, articleId);
        }
    }

    public static void closeWriter() throws IOException {
        unigram_writer.close();
        bigram_writer.close();
        trigram_writer.close();
    }
}
```

I call 'load' for each article I iterate through, and the ArrayLists are just lists of the ngrams that need to be added.

The program starts out fast enough, but after about 100,000 articles, it becomes impossibly slow. I'm assuming the writer is merging data into one SSTable on the fly, which is slowing things down immensely as the number of items grows too large.

Any ideas on ways around this?

Comment: Did you ever find anything out about this problem? It becomes almost unusable after a short while.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never made any headway with this. I ended up leaning towards HPC with Spark and producing the relevant data on the fly instead of preloading it into Cassandra. Resource-intensive, but I was lucky to have enough.

Answer (score 0):

So this helped. I noticed that the more records that were created in the same input directory the longer the import got. I have looked around and it appears that this is a problem due to the size of the index and cassandra having to rebuild it each time it writes. I have not verified this but it made sense from the result I saw. Here is my solution to recreate the table writer and create a new directory so that the building of the index will be much quicker.

It is not perfect but it is dramatically faster.

```
class CassandraLoader {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CassandraLoader.class
            .getName());

    // After half a million records we will rotate the directory for efficiency
    private static final int MAX_RECORD_COUNT = 500000;

    private CQLSSTableWriter tableWriter;

    private final CsvIOFactory csvIOFactory = CsvIOFactory.createFactory(
            createCsvConfig(), AdBlockLog.class);;

    private final CsvDeserializer deSerializer;

    private final String cqlKeySpace;

    private final String cqlTable;

    /**
     * This is the total number of output directories we have processed.
     */
    private int rolloverFileCount = 0;

    /**
     * Output directory name.
     */
    private String outputDirectory;

    /**
     * Constructor that initializes the output cql keyspace and the cql table where
     * the data needed to be stored.
     * 
     * @param cqlKeySpace
     * @param cqlTable
     * @param outputDirectory
     */
    protected CassandraLoader(final String cqlKeySpace, final String cqlTable,
            final String outputDirectory) {
        this.cqlKeySpace = cqlKeySpace;
        this.cqlTable = cqlTable;
        this.outputDirectory = outputDirectory;
        // Create a new Desieralizer.
        deSerializer = csvIOFactory.createDeserializer();

        tableWriter = createTableWriter(outputDirectory, rolloverFileCount);
    }

    public int load(final String s3Bucket, final String s3Regex)
            throws InvalidRequestException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, IOException {

        int totalRecordCount = 0;
        int rolloverRecordCount = 0;


        logger.info("Loading files from bucket " + s3Bucket + " with regex "
                + s3Regex);

        final List<String> s3FileKeys = S3Util.listBucketToKeys(s3Bucket, s3Regex);
        logger.info("Found " + s3FileKeys.size() + " total s3 files");

        for (String s3fileKey : s3FileKeys) {
            logger.info("Processing file " + s3fileKey);
            int recordsProcessed = loadCsvFromS3Bulk(s3Bucket, s3fileKey);
            totalRecordCount += recordsProcessed;
            rolloverRecordCount += recordsProcessed;

            logger.info("Total Record Count " + totalRecordCount);
            logger.info("Rollover Record Count " + rolloverRecordCount);

            if (rolloverRecordCount >= MAX_RECORD_COUNT) {
                tableWriter.close();
                tableWriter = createTableWriter(outputDirectory,
                        ++rolloverFileCount);
                rolloverRecordCount = 0;
            }

        }
        return totalRecordCount;
    }

    private int loadCsvFromS3Bulk(final String bucketName, final String key)
            throws IOException, InvalidRequestException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        // Have to close all of these
        InputStream s3InputStream = null;
        InputStream gzStream = null;
        InputStreamReader bufReader = null;

        int recordsProcessed = 0;

        try {
            s3InputStream = S3Util.getFileInputStream(bucketName, key);
            gzStream = new GZIPInputStream(s3InputStream);

            bufReader = new InputStreamReader(gzStream,
                    StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

            deSerializer.open(bufReader);

            for (; deSerializer.hasNext(); recordsProcessed++) {
                AdBlockLog abl = deSerializer.next();
                tableWriter.addRow(getRowMap(abl));
            }

        } finally {
            deSerializer.close(true);
            bufReader.close();
            gzStream.close();
            s3InputStream.close();
        }

        MemoryUtils.printUsage(logger);
        return recordsProcessed;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        tableWriter.close();
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected Map<String, Object> getRowMap(final CassandraEntity casEntity)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        Map<String, Object> rowMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        for (Field f : casEntity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class)) {
                Column columnAnnotation = f.getAnnotation(Column.class);
                Class<?> clazz = f.getType();
                f.setAccessible(true);

                logger.finest("adding column with class " + clazz.getName());
                if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(BigDecimal.class)) {
                    BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) f.get(casEntity);
                    rowMap.put(columnAnnotation.name(), (value == null ? null
                            : value.doubleValue()));
                    continue;
                }
                // Anything other than BigDecimal we can just add.
                if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                    String value = (String) f.get(casEntity);
                    // I think this should save space
                    rowMap.put(columnAnnotation.name(),
                            (value == null || value.isEmpty()) ? null : value);
                }
                rowMap.put(columnAnnotation.name(), f.get(casEntity));
            }
        }

        return rowMap;
    }


    /**
     * Create a new tableWriter. This is most important for doing rollover 
     * to a new directory to increase speed and efficiency.
     * 
     * The output will be stored in the same directory where the application is
     * being ran in the format of cqlKeySpace/outputDirectoryName_iterator
     * 
     * ex.
     * s3dump/dt=2015-02-01_1
     *  
     * @param outputDirectoryName The directory name that you want to write the output to
     * @param iteration The iteration that will be appended to the directory.
     * @return A newly created {@link CQLSSTableWriter} 
     */
    private final CQLSSTableWriter createTableWriter(
            String outputDirectoryName, int iteration) {
        final String directoryName = String.format(cqlKeySpace + "/%s_%s",
                outputDirectoryName, Integer.toString(iteration));

        final File currentOutputDirectory = new File(directoryName);

        if (!currentOutputDirectory.exists()) {
            logger.info("Creating sstable director "
                    + currentOutputDirectory.getName());
            currentOutputDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        String schema = String.format(AdBlockLog.AD_BLOCK_LOG_SCHEMA,
                cqlKeySpace, cqlTable);

        String insert = String.format(AdBlockLog.AD_BLOCK_LOG_INSERT_STMT,
                cqlKeySpace, cqlTable);

        return CQLSSTableWriter.builder()
                .inDirectory(currentOutputDirectory.getAbsolutePath())
                .withPartitioner(new Murmur3Partitioner())
                .withBufferSizeInMB(128).forTable(schema).using(insert).build();
    }

    private static final CsvConfiguration createCsvConfig() {
        CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration();
        config.setFieldDelimiter(',');
        return config;

    }
}
```